# how to solve this undefined variable error in this code?

Tags: php

```
<html>

<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file_field"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I get an error message as below:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: file_field in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 113
```

I tried defining `$file_field` on the top of the page but the problem with that is I don't get the file name in the MySQL database instead i get just `Array` and I also get the following error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 114
```

Has anyone any idea? Help.

```
<?php

function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

//Config Section    
//Set file upload path
$path = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/images/'; //with trailing slash
//Set max file size in bytes
$max_size = 1000000;
//Set default file extension whitelist
$whitelist_ext = array('jpg','png','gif');
//Set default file type whitelist
$whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

//The Validation
// Create an array to hold any output
$out = array('error'=>null);

if (!$file_field) {
$out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
}

if (!$path) {
$out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
return $out;
}

//Make sure that there is a file
if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

// Get filename
$file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
$name = $file_info['filename'];
$ext = $file_info['extension'];

//Check file has the right extension           
if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
$out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
}

//Check that the file is of the right type
if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
$out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
}

//Check that the file is not too big
if ($_FILES[$file_field]["size"] > $max_size) {
$out['error'][] = "File is too big";
}

//If $check image is set as true
if ($check_image) {
if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
$out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
}
}

//Create full filename including path
if ($random_name) {
// Generate random filename
$tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
$out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
}     
$newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
} else {
$newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
}

//Check if file already exists on server
if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
$out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
//The file has not correctly validated
return $out;
} 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
//Success
$out['filepath'] = $path;
$out['filename'] = $newname;
return $out;
} else {
$out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
}

} else {
$out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
return $out;
}      
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("simple_login", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (photo)
VALUES ('$file_field')");


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You have posted code that give you notice or error but what you have tried to solved this problem ?

Comment: use `$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name']` or `$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']`

Comment: i tried defining field_name like this on the top of the page...$field_name = ['field_name']...when i do this i get... Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 114 and the file name doesn't appear in my MySQL database...Just "Array" appears

Answer (score 0):

$file_field is being called outside its scope

if you want to resolve this issue use the global keyword

```
global $file_field
```

Please read about [PHP Global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `$_FILES['file_field']` instead of `$file_field`.

it's not needed to pass `$file_field` variable to function.

**Modified Version of Your Code**

```
function uploadFile ($check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

//Config Section    
//Set file upload path
$path = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/images/'; //with trailing slash
//Set max file size in bytes
$max_size = 1000000;
//Set default file extension whitelist
$whitelist_ext = array('jpg','png','gif');
//Set default file type whitelist
$whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

//The Validation
// Create an array to hold any output
$out = array('error'=>null);

if (!$_FILES['file_field']) {
$out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
}

if (!$path) {
$out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
return $out;
}

//Make sure that there is a file
if((!empty($_FILES['file_field']['name'])) && ($_FILES['file_field']['error'] == 0)) {

// Get filename
$file_info = pathinfo($_FILES['file_field']['name']);
$name = $file_info['filename'];
$ext = $file_info['extension'];

//Check file has the right extension           
if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
$out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
}

//Check that the file is of the right type
if (!in_array($_FILES['file_field']["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
$out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
}

//Check that the file is not too big
if ($_FILES['file_field']["size"] > $max_size) {
$out['error'][] = "File is too big";
}

//If $check image is set as true
if ($check_image) {
if (!getimagesize($_FILES['file_field']['tmp_name'])) {
$out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
}
}

//Create full filename including path
if ($random_name) {
// Generate random filename
$tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
$out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
}     
$newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
} else {
$newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
}

//Check if file already exists on server
if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
$out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
//The file has not correctly validated
return $out;
} 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_field']['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
//Success
$out['filepath'] = $path;
$out['filename'] = $newname;
return $out;
} else {
$out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
}

} else {
$out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
return $out;
}      
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("simple_login", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (photo)
VALUES ('{$_FILES[file_field][tmp_name]}')");
/*
it's better to save it like this :
$content = file_get_contents($_FILES['file_field']['tmp_name']);
$content = base64_encode($data);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (photo)
VALUES ('{$content}')");
// but you can later use base64_decode() to convert data.
*/

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: @user1929075 and after changes, `$_FILES[$file_field]` should be `$_FILES['file_field']`

Comment: I tried doing that but I got this: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _FILES in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 11  .....could you just modify my code according to your corrections and post it again?

Comment: @user1929075 answer edited, also read comments at the end of snippet. tnx

Comment: the code you edited worked but it isn't showing any error message..I mean like whatever file I try to upload it accepts the file and insert the file name to database...It doesn't check anything at all..the maximum file size isn't being checked...nothing is working..It just uploads without any restrictions I set..you have any idea?